# How to add an enity that would contain multiple words

Tags: artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding

How to define an entity in Luis that would consist of multiople words.E.g. I want "La Quinta Inn & Suites" to be identifed as a single entity "HotelName"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface takes a little getting used to.
Left click on the first word, then move to the last word and click again.
that will allow you to set the entity for multiple words.
Rod

Comment: Use this on Chrome browser. Edge is having an issue with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a machine-learned entity, provide several utterances with varying word length and word choice, including variations of the hotel/company name in utterances, then label the hotel/company name in each as the entity.

If you want to white-list the entity for exact matches, create a list entity of hotel/company names and make sure each hotel/company has synonyms with all the variations -- because it is an exact match.

Learn more about [types of entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-concept-entity-types).